# calculate salary in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have a starting salary as 100,000.

I want to calculate 10% as salary increase and 5% as bonus increase for next 5 years.

Not able to figure out the oracle query. I tried lag function and connect by dual. but did not succeed.

So something like the following:

```
year    salary    bonus   total_salary 
1       100,000   5000    105,000
```

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. Once that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, include the relevant portions of your SQL, and ask a specific question about that SQL, and we can try to assist.

Comment: This is a fairly simple calculation, so it would be more useful for you as well as for us if you include your current best attempt and what is wrong with it - if it gets errors, or wrong results, etc. Your example seems to be increasing the bonus by 10%, not 5%, which is also confusing.

Comment: can you use pl/sql or just sql ?

Comment: got the answer from GMB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a recursive query:

```
with cte(year, salary, bonus) as (
    select 1, 100000, 5000 from dual
    union all
    select year + 1, salary * 1.10, bonus * 1.05 from cte where year < 20
)
select c.*, salary + bonus total_salary from cte c
```